# Image not being retrieved from browser cache - gwt upload

Tags: caching, gwt, browser

I am using gwt-upload to upload an image to my server. In the response back to the client, I am getting the file url in this format.

http://myServer.com/myApplication/servlet.gupld?show=GWTU-036386735388077796

Now, I try to make a copy of this image on my client to enable cropping by the user. However, when I create an img tag with this same url, the image is being retrieved from the server and not from the cache. Can somebody please provide a solution for this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are using custom servlet to return images. Do you set correct HTTP headers to the response, so the browser knows that images can be cached?

[Here](http://onjava.com/onjava/excerpt/jebp_3/index2.html) is a tutorial how to implement it using servlets

Comment: Thank you so much jusio. I set the 'Expires' header and it worked fine. Thanks again for your help.